# Accessing project prefix inside the included ant file

Tags: ant

Is it possible to access "as" prefix inside the included ant file 
(i.e. to access "as" attribute value specified in include task)

file including.xml:

```
<project name="myproject">
  <include file="included.xml" as="nested" />
</project>
```

file included.xml:

```
<project>
  <echo message="I am included into ${ant.project.name} as ${SomePropertyIAskAbout}" />
</project>
```

Desired output: "I am included into myproject as nested"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<include>` executes an included buildfile as if were in the including buildfile. Having both files reference a custom property will do the trick.

### including.xml

```
<project name="myproject">
    <property name="including-as-attribute" value="nested" />
    <include file="included.xml" as="${including-as-attribute}" />
</project>
```

### included.xml

```
<project>
    <fail unless="including-as-attribute"/>
    <echo message="I am included into ${ant.project.name} as ${including-as-attribute}" />
</project>
```

### Output of `ant -f including.xml`

```
 [echo] I am included into myproject as nested
```